# Which sentence has more common words with the given list of words

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I have a list of common words, and several sentences.

I need to check which sentence has more common words.

I have one function that counts the total number of common words in a given sentence, and I can use it to compare those counts for different sentences:

```
def get_words_count_in_sentence(text, words_list):
    cnt = 0
    for word in words:
        cnt += text.lower().count(word.lower())
    return cnt
```

But the problem is that I also need to consider how many *distinct* words from the list the sentence contains.

For example: if the first sentence contains 10 times the first word of the list, and the second sentence contains 1 time the first word of the list, 2 times the second word, and 1 time the third word, then the second sentence should be considered more similar.

How can I update my code to have this priority implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let your function return a tuple, where the first number is the number of distinct words, and the second is what you already calculated. This way the second number will break the tie when two phrases use the same number of distinct words (that match):

```
def get_words_count_in_sentence(text, words):
    total = 0
    distinct = 0
    text = text.lower()
    for word in words:
        freq = text.count(word)
        if freq > 0:
            distinct += 1
            total += freq
    return distinct, total


words = ["bad", "ugly", "dirty", "horrible"]

i = get_words_count_in_sentence("What a bad, bad day. So bad, it makes me feel bad.", words)
j = get_words_count_in_sentence("What a bad day. The weather is horrible and the windows are dirty.", words)

print(i)  # (1, 4)
print(j)  # (3, 3)
print(j > i)  # True
```